# how to extend tools options in visualstudio

Tags: visual-studio

I have found in Internet some video sample that explains how to add my own page into Tools-> Window dialog. But it's not clear for me how and where should I save my own settings?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely need to create a Visual Studio Add-In, get a handle to the menu item you want to modify and go from there.

-Shaun

Comment: I have created VS Integration package and it allows me to add my custom page into Tools - Options but I don't know how to SAVE my own settings that I change using this page. And I don't interested to handle some menu item, my question is about something else.